# SAS User-Defined Function with Optional Parameters

Tags: sas, user-defined-functions

Is there a way to create a user-defined function using `PROC FCMP` that allows optional parameters?

For example, I've written a simple udf in SAS that checks if a string is numeric or not.

```
PROC FCMP OUTLIB = fcns.functions.all; 
   FUNCTION isNumeric(string $);
      result = ifn(verify(string, " -0123456789") = 0, 1, 0);
      RETURN(result);
   ENDSUB;
QUIT;
```

Now I would like to check for symbols often associated with numbers, such as `$`, `,`, and `.`, but only if the user specifies. Something like this:

```
PROC FCMP OUTLIB = fcns.functions.all; 
   FUNCTION isNumeric(string $, symbols=0);

      IF symbols = 0 THEN
         result = ifn(verify(string, " -0123456789") = 0, 1, 0);
      ELSE
         result = ifn(verify(string, " -0123456789$,.") = 0, 1, 0);

      RETURN(result);
   ENDSUB;
QUIT;
```

Running the above code gives an error. I've searched online, but haven't been able to find anything on it. Are optional parameters even possible? If they're not, would it be better to create one function with two required parameters, or two separate functions? I lean toward having one function, but thought I'd open up the question.

Comment: What does the PROC FCMP documentation say?  Usually to determine if a string is a number you can just read it with the COMMA informat and if it returns non missing you are good.  Takes care of 1.4E5 and that sort of thing.

Comment: What is the error message? Did it not compile? Or did it cause an error when you tried to use it?

Comment: @tom When I try to compile (may not be the right word) the function, it gives me `Syntax error, expecting one of the following: $, (, ), ',', HASH, HITER, [, {.` But I think @allan is correct, they just don't allow it, with the "exception" of an array parameter.

Comment: @data_null_, thanks for the tip, I'll keep it in mind. Although this was really just an example function so I could get the hang of creating udf's in SAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to define optional parameters using fcmp.  It's a real shame!

The closest you can come is to define your last value as an array (of values), using the `varargs` argument.  The major problem with this is that all the values must be of the same type.

See [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002975331.htm) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought was the case. SAS documentation isn't always the clearest, at least not to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you were trying to do with the `=0` in the function definition, but that is what is causing it to not compile.

```
376     FUNCTION isNumeric(string $, symbols=0);
                                            -
                                            22
                                            200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: $, (, ), ',', DICTIONARY, DNARY, HASH, HITER, VARCHAR, [, {.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

So just remove  it.

```
proc fcmp outlib = work.functions.all;
function isnumeric(string $, symbols);
  if symbols then
    result = ifn(verify(string, " -0123456789$,.") = 0, 1, 0);
  else
    result = ifn(verify(string, " -0123456789") = 0, 1, 0);
  return(result);
endsub;
quit;
```

Comment: I think with the =0 he was trying to make an optional parameter and give it a default value, like you would with a macro language keyword parameter. Is that not possible with FCMP?  From a quick google, it didn’t look promising. e.g. https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Define-optional-argument-to-function-FCMP/td-p/280475

Comment: @Quentin is correct. I could easily remove the `=0`, but that would cause the parameter to be required, when I was hoping to make an optional parameter.

Comment: Not sure how adding `=0` makes a difference in whether a parameter is `required`.  I would think that the logic coded into the function is what determines whether a parameter as required.